How can you use std::views::zip with std::ranges::for_each?
With C++ foreach loops we can write:
void process(int i);
...
for(auto i : items)
    process(i);

With ranges in C++20, this can be written as:
std::ranges::for_each(items, process);

With std::views::zip in C++23 we can write:
void process(int a, int b);
for(auto [a, b] : std::views::zip(itemsA, itemsB))
    process(a, b);

How can I use std::ranges::for_each to call the original process(int, int) function?

https://godbolt.org/z/dP6Eaffvs

std::views::zip produces "tuple-like" values but the original function takes two arguments. In other words, std::ranges::for_each wants process() to take a tuple:
void process(std::tuple<int, int> t);
...
std::ranges::for_each(std::views::zip(itemsA, itemsB), process);

But rewriting process to take a tuple is probably bad. It really needs an adaptor, for which a straight forward and generic solution is a lambda calling std::apply():
std::ranges::for_each(std::views::zip(itemsA, itemsB),
                      [](auto t){
                          std::apply(process, t);
                      });

Optionally unpack the arguments in the lambda, just like the original for loop. Error messages are nicer than std::apply if the arguments don't match:
std::ranges::for_each(std::views::zip(itemsA, itemsB),
                      [](auto t){
                          auto [a, b] = t;
                          process(a, b);
                      });


Stop reading to remain in the world of the practical. What about automating the adaptor that must call std::apply? Not a good idea. So anyway...
for pedagogical purposes only
We'll need a way to deduce the function parameter types as we'll get these from the function and not the zip_view's tuple. This is why the lambda was a good option - its parameters would be deduced from the zip_view instead and you'd probably get better error messages for a mismatch.
template <class T>
struct function_traits;

// Function pointer specialization
template <class R, class... Args>
struct function_traits<R(*)(Args...)> {
    using args_tuple_type = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template <class T>
using function_args_tuple = typename function_traits<T>::args_tuple_type;

There's a couple of options now. We can make a function that returns a lambda:
template<class Func>
auto apply_to(Func&& func)
{
    using Tuple = function_args_tuple<std::decay_t<Func>>;
    return [func](const Tuple& t){return std::apply(func, t); };
}

...

std::ranges::for_each(std::views::zip(itemsA, itemsB), apply_to(process));

Or better yet we can make a template function that calls std::apply directly, taking the function as a template value.
template<auto func>
auto apply_to(const function_args_tuple<std::decay_t<decltype(func)>>& t)
{
    return std::apply(func, t);
}

...

std::ranges::for_each(std::views::zip(itemsA, itemsB), apply_to<process>);


from where you get this [](auto [a, b]){?

Wow. Ty, @MarekR! I was 100% sure I tested all this while writing it (even copy/pasted that block from godbolt) but clearly I confused myself. Updated.
